# How to use js from library inside data-bind scope

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, data-bind

I'm trying to use sortable with below code:

```
 <ul id="sortable-list">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span class="sort-handle">Sortable Item #1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
          <span class="sort-handle">Sortable Item #2</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
           <span class="sort-handle">Sortable Item #3</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "jquery/ui"
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sortable-list').sortable({handle: '.sort-handle'});
        });
    });
    </script>
```

It is working fine.

But if my code is inside a div defined data-bind it doesn't work:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'testScope'">
<ul id="sortable-list">
        <li>
            <div>
                <span class="sort-handle">Sortable Item #1</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
              <span class="sort-handle">Sortable Item #2</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
               <span class="sort-handle">Sortable Item #3</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        require([
            "jquery",
            "jquery/ui"
        ], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#sortable-list').sortable({handle: '.sort-handle'});
            });
        });
        </script>
</div>
```

Can someone explain and guide me how to fix it? Thank you very much.